# Determine whether the given statement for a Cauchy problem of a partial differential equation is true or false?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, compactness

> **Problem:** Let $a$ be a fixed real constant. Consider the first order partial differential equation $~u_t+au_x=0, ~~x\in\mathbb R,~ t>0~$ with the initial data $~u(x,0)=u_0(x),~~x\in\mathbb R~$ where $~u_0~$ is a continuously differentiable function. Then determine whether the following statement is true or false:
> If $~u_0~$ vanishes outside a compact set then for each fixed $~T>0~$ there exists a compact set $~K_T\subset \mathbb R~$ such that $~u(x,T)~$ vanishes for $~x\notin K_T~.$

**My work:** By Lagrange's subsidiary equation $$\dfrac{dx}{a}=\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{du}{0}$$
Which implies, $~~u=c_1~$ and $~x-at=c_2~$ where $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$ are arbitrary independent constants.
 Therefore the solution of the given PDE is $~u(x,t)=\phi(x-at),~$ where $~\phi(x)~$ is an arbitrary function.
The given initial data, $~u(x,0)=u_0(x)\implies u_0(x)=\phi(x)~.$
Hence the solution of the given PDE is $~u(x,t)= u_0(x-at)~.$

From here I am totally in dark. I have no idea how to proceed further. Please help to solve the problem.

**Note:** If $~u_0(x)~$ is a bounded function, then $~u_0(x-at)~$ is also bounded function and hence $~u(x,t)~$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You have already solved the problem. Lets say $[L,U]\in\mathbb{R}$ is the compact set outside of which $u_0$ vanishes. Since you have the given solution $u(x,t)=u_0(x-at)$ you just have to shift the compact set accordingly $K_T=[L+aT,U+aT]$.

Now lets try it out. Lets assume $x<L+aT\Rightarrow x-aT<L\Rightarrow u(x-aT,T)=u_0(x-aT)=0$ Thus, for $x<L+aT$, the function $u(x,T)$ vanishes. (The same holds true for the upper limit)

The intuition behind it is that these (transport) equations have a finite (in this case even constant) speed of propagation. Meaning information can only move with a certain velocity. This is not necessarily true for all PDEs. For example the heat equation features an infinite speed of propagation meaning that initial data on a compact set will spread to the whole domain as soon as the clock starts.

Comment: So the given statement is true here. Thank you for your answer. @maxmilgram